# Access Thread.CurrentPrincipal when binding with NInject in Owin context

Tags: asp.net-web-api, ninject, owin

I need to access my claims when binding my services, but appears that Ninject bind occurs before [HttpMessageHandlerAdapter](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Http.Owin/HttpMessageHandlerAdapter.cs) sets the Thread.CurrentPrincipal so I cannot access my claims when I'm binding my services. I tried this

```
kernel.Bind<IMyService>().ToMethod(x => GetMyService());

private static IMyService GetMyService()
{
    var principal = Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
    var userId = [GetUserIdFromPrincipalClaims]
    return new MyService(userId);
}
```

But the claims list is empty, if I access Thread.CurrentPrincipal claims list from any action I can get an userId. How can I access my claims list  when binding?

Answer (score 0):

Since identity claims are a run-time value, I would say it can't be done (easily). However, one approach involving the decorator pattern and an abstract factory might look like this:

```
class MyServiceDecoraptor : IMyService
{
    private readonly IMyServiceFactory _myServiceFactory;
    public MyServiceDecoraptor(IMyServiceFactory myServiceFactory)
    {
        _myServiceFactory = myserviceFactory
    }

    public void MyServiceMethod()
    {
        var principal = Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
        var userid = GetUserId(principal);
        _myServiceFactory.Create(userid).MyServiceMethod();
    }
    //more code here
   }
```